# tracing connection-url of data source with JPA

Tags: jpa, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, websphere-8

How to print/show the url-connection to the database from a Java code?

It's a Java EE 6 classic application with `persistence.xml` (JNDI entry to Jboss 7 or WAS 8 datasource, JPA/hibernate)